# Override producer config

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to override the parameter without rebooting the broker. I use the parameter in the connector config

```
     'producer.override.max.request.size' = 2097152
```

but I get the error

```
The 'None' policy does not allow 'max.request.size' to be overridden in the connector configuration.
```

Is it possible to change this parameter through the connector configuration or is it necessary to restart the broker?

Comment: You mean restart the worker? Kafka Connect never needs the broker to be restarted

Comment: I was wrong. restart Connect

Answer (score 2):

> The 'None' policy does not allow...

You need to edit the `connector.client.config.override.policy` on the **worker**, not the broker, then restart it. Then you can modify any client property in the connectors

> The default implementation is `None`. The other possible policies in the framework include `All` and `Principal`.